# Object properties not displaying on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Vd5RRZXIyo) on the MERN stack because I want to see how all of the pieces weave together to better understand it. My problem is that when I go to load the server object properties that are entered (`studentName` and `regNo`) on the client side are not appearing, except for those with defaults. When I go to `http://localhost:5000/students/` I see the following:

[image]

On the server side I have the following:

`/server/models/student.js` contains

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const studentSchema= mongoose.Schema({
    regNo: Number,
    studentName: String,
    grade:  {
        type: String, default: 'hello'
    },
    section: {
        type: String, default: 'Z'
    }

})

const student = mongoose.model('student', studentSchema);
export default student;
```

`/server/controllers/student.js` contains:

```
import StudentData from '../models/student.js';

export const getStudents = async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        console.log("This try statement worked")
        const allStudents= await StudentData.find(); //Goes to model and finds student data if available
        res.status(200).json(allStudents);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message});
        
    }
};

export const createStudent= async (req, res) =>{
    const student= req.body;

    const newStudent= new StudentData(student); //model(variable)

    try {
        await newStudent.save();
        res.status(201).json(newStudent);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({message: error.message})
        
    }
}
```

`/server/routes/students.js` contains

```
import express from "express";
import { getStudents, createStudent} from "../controllers/student.js"
import student from '../models/student.js';
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", getStudents); //res = response req=request
router.post("/", createStudent); 
export default router;
```

On the client side I have `/client/components/createStudent/createStudent.js`:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: '25ch',
    },
  },
}));



export default function Create() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [student, setStudent]= useState({
    regNo: 0,
    studentName: '',
    grade: '',
    section: ''
  }); //React hook. Updates data in text fields on frontend
  const createStudent = () => {
  axios.post("http://localhost:5000/students", student)


} 
  return (
    <>
    <h2>Create Student</h2>
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Registration No." variant="outlined" value={student.regNo} onChange={(event) =>{
        setStudent({...student, regNo: event.target.value})
      }}  />
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Name" variant="outlined" value={student.studentName} onChange={(event) =>{
        setStudent({...student, studentName: event.target.value})
      }} /><TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Grade" variant="outlined" value={student.grade} onChange={(event) =>{
        setStudent({...student, grade: event.target.value})
      }} /><TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Section" variant="outlined" value={student.section} onChange={(event) =>{
        setStudent({...student, section: event.target.value})
      }} />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={createStudent}  >
        Create 
      </Button>
    </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Earlier I was getting the following error in the Chrome console:

[image]

But I fixed it (or so I thought), by adding this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US) as per the suggestion in [this article](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9). Could this be why my properties are not showing up?

Answer (score 0):

You need install cors

do `npm install cors`

Than apply it on your router

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors"; //Import Cors
import { getStudents, createStudent} from "../controllers/student.js"
import student from '../models/student.js';
const app = express(); //Change it from express.Router() to express()

app.use(cors()); //applied cors here
app.get("/", getStudents); //res = response req=request
app.post("/", createStudent); 
export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use the project in production in the future, don't use `cors`. It is a major security risk. Instead, use the proxy feature built-in in Create React App (assume that's what you are using).

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Of course, if you are simply using this project as a sandbox or trial and error, then it doesn't matter. Just remember not to do this in production.